# How to remote URL in modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I only want load a URL in my modal dialog. Anyone have idea or solution?

This is what I've tried:

```
<a href="facebook.com" class="ls-modal">Preview Live In Modal</a>

<div id="trimModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use an `iframe` inside the modal, and set its `src` to the value of `href`.

Comment: could you explain your code dude? how to load href outer modal dialog?

Comment: [This section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target) of bootstrap docs may help.

Comment: Removed clutter from title